# Does Windows Phone 8 support GIF images?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8, gif

I recently was able to successfully set an Image's source as a GIF image, using:

```
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://imageurl/image.gif")
```

I currently have to use a substantial amount of extra code to convert GIF images to PNG images, since Windows Phone 7 does not support GIF images. Is this a new officially supported feature in Windows Phone 8? Does it really support GIF images, or was my experience some sort of glitch?(Maybe an GIF file that was really in PNG format) I was wondering because I can't find this feature anywhere by searching, all that comes up is WP7 related content. I'd think it would be a such a large improvement that it would be mentioned somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff462087%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_ImageSupport) GIF is officially supported by Windows Phone 8

Also: do not write your own code to turn GIF's into PNG's [do a batch conversion](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/)

You could also use [the .NET Image Tools](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/) to use the GIF's on Windows Phone 7

The only thing that might get in your way is a badly formatted GIF or an animated GIF.

Comment: Ugh, you beat me to it. Only because the emulator broke my internet! :P +1

Comment: Strange. That article applies to WP7 and WP8, but I know that WP7 does not support GIF's. I was using .NET Image Tools, the image files are downloaded from a server that I do not have access to.